# could I call custom javascript file by dart

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

i have a very big javascript file , want to call it by dart /flutter app.
searched a lot, 
tried js, and flutter_webview_plugin.

in fact I don't want to create a webview, just have a bit class of js file , want to call it from dart with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It's better If you add **more info** or explain **what you are trying to archive?**

Because, The solution may differ depending on the use cases. The **WebView** commonly use to **embed** the **web based applications**.

Anyway, Flutter officially has a package called `dart:js` to interoperating with JavaScript.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-js/dart-js-library.html